# Using Apply family of functions on mts objects

Tags: r, apply

Using apply (or sapply) on an mts object removes its time series properties when sending to function. How should I apply same function (with ts input and ts output) on each of times series in an mts object and return it (preferably as mts) [I mean besides using for loops]?

For example suppose I write a function that returns the trend of a time series (using stl)

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
      return(stl(x,"per")$time.series[,2])
}
```

Now for a sample mts

```
z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(90), 30, 3), start=c(1961, 1), frequency=4)
class(z)
```

Sending only one of the time series works correct:

```
myfunc(z[,1]) # works correctly, returns the trend of first series
```

My function is not designed for multiple time series so:

```
myfunc(z) # will not work returning the error below

Error in stl(x, "per") : only univariate series are allowed
```

Using apply on the mts object send each of the time series as a vector, not preserving its time series properties (tsp):

```
apply(z,2,myfunc) # will not work returning the error below

Error in stl(x, "per") : 
series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

Comment: True, `apply` will remove attributes, but `sapply` should not do so. `ts` objects are weird. They often have printing methods that mislead the user as to their true structures, so you should be using str() on them.

Comment: Would you please provide code on using sapply in for my example? I found out that using sapply raised the same error as it just calls apply itself.

Comment: And about `ts` objects weirdness! I don't use or rely on any printing method, I _do_ need to know its time series properties, i.e. `tsp`, which is just a vector of length 3, indicating the start, the end and the frequency of time series data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way around this, is to work with the indices instead of a clean `apply` :

```
sapply(seq_len(ncol(z)),function(i) myfunc(z[,i]))
```

`apply` puts clean vectors inside the function, because it first converts an object to a matrix. By using the `[` function defined for time series objects, you are sure that you extract a valid time series each time.

Answer (score 3):

I change the myfunc to check if it have a ts object as parameter x.

If x is not a ts , it is converted to ts object as **stl** need this parameter type.

```
  myfunc <- function(x,...){
        y <- x
       if(class(x) != 'ts') {
         dots <- c(...)
         y <- ts(x,start=c(dots[1], dots[2]), frequency=dots[3])
       }
       return(stl(y,"per")$time.series[,2])
     }
  ## no need to conversion (already ts object)
  myfunc(z[,1])


  ## mts object ( here we give parameter necessary for conversion)
  apply(z,2,myfunc,1961,1,4)
```

Comment: and if I have to have the outcome as mts itself: ts(apply(z,2,myfunc,1961,1,4),start=c(1961, 1), frequency=4)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that we do not always write the `myfunc' function. Most often we just use someone else's code.