# apply a function to a timeseries object

Tags: r, time-series

say I have the following ts object in R.

```
x <- ts(data = matrix(1:10, 5, 2), start = 1/12, deltat = 1/12)
```

Now  I want to apply a function f to each entry of this time series: the function f depends on the value of the time series and the corresponding time, for example:

```
f <- function(z, time){z*time}
```

I am looking for an efficient way to do this: so far I only managed some kind of work around solution like this:

```
timex <- seq(from = 1/12, by = 1/12, length = 5)
apply(x, 2, function(y){ apply(cbind(y, timex),1, function(z) f(z[1], z[2]))})
```

This solution provides the right result but I quite sure that there is a more direct approach.

I am looking for a method which works for more "complicated functions" f: in particular it is not possible to call f(x, time(x)) directly, if length(x)>1.

For me, it is not important that the time series is in ts format, so if there is a solution for a different time series format, that I am all in favor for it. The most important thing here for me is performance.
Also the final result does not have to be a time series object.

Do you guys have any hints?
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
the problem seems to be that x loses its ts properties once apply is used.
In particular it is not possible to use the *time* command anymore.

```
apply(x, 2, class)
 Series 1  Series 2 
"integer" "integer"

class(x)
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

**EDIT 2:** 
I have been asked to provide an example for a "more complicate function f:
This is a function which computes the value of some financial product.

```
f  <- function(s0, t){
  option.times <- 1:20/2
  tau <- option.times[option.times >= t] - t

  d = (log(1.5/s0) - 0.0098*tau)/(0.0098* sqrt(tau))

  p1 <- pnorm(d)
  p2 <- s0 / 1.5* exp((1/2*0.02^2 + 0.0098)*tau) * pnorm(d-0.02*sqrt(tau)) 
  sum((p1-p2)*exp(-0.02*tau))*100

}
```

I cannot provide the time series I am working with: but it is a 530x10000 time series with weekly data (time(x) starts at 0 and progresses with deltat = 1/52).
For this function f and my time series I get that

```
> system.time(apply(x, 2, function(y){ apply(cbind(y, timex),1, function(z) f(z[1], z[2]))}))
       User      System verstrichen 
      69.62        0.03       69.75 
> system.time(mapply(f, x, time(x)))
       User      System verstrichen 
      79.01        0.06       79.12
```

so mapply is slightly slower than using apply twice.

Comment: Doesn't `apply(x, 2, function(x) f(x, timex))` return the same result as your `apply` call?

Comment: Doesn't `x * timex` give the same result?

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks:
the solutions should work also for more complicated functions f:
In particular, it is not possible that the input x of f is a vector.
I update the question

Comment: are you looking for `time(x)`?

Comment: no, I am aware of the function time(x).
But as soon as i use it inside the apply functions time(x) does not work properly anymore. I guess that x looses its ts properties along the way.

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583817/using-apply-family-of-functions-on-mts-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply` to use multiple vectors as input:

```
x <- ts(data = matrix(1:10, 5, 2), start = 1/12, deltat = 1/12)
f <- function(z, time){z*time}
mapply(f, x, time(x))
#>  [1] 0.08333333 0.33333333 0.75000000 1.33333333 2.08333333 0.50000000
#>  [7] 1.16666667 2.00000000 3.00000000 4.16666667
```

**EDIT:**
I can reproduce your timings with the realistic function and a realistic amount of data:

```
n <- 530
m <- 10000
x <- ts(data = matrix(rlnorm(n * m), n, m), start = 0, deltat = 1/52)
f  <- function(s0, t){
  option.times <- 1:20/2
  tau <- option.times[option.times >= t] - t

  d = (log(1.5/s0) - 0.0098*tau)/(0.0098* sqrt(tau))

  p1 <- pnorm(d)
  p2 <- s0 / 1.5* exp((1/2*0.02^2 + 0.0098)*tau) * pnorm(d-0.02*sqrt(tau)) 
  sum((p1-p2)*exp(-0.02*tau))*100
}
timex <- time(x)
system.time(r1 <- apply(x, 2, function(y){ apply(cbind(y, timex),1, function(z) f(z[1], z[2]))}))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>      67.002       0.059      67.089
system.time(r2 <- matrix(mapply(f, x, time(x)), n, m))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>      78.975       0.244      79.250
all(r1 == r2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

However, your function allows for at least partial vectorization so that it is enough to do an (explicit) loop over all rows instead of an (implicit) loop aver all matrix elements:

```
g  <- function(s0, t){
  option.times <- 1:20/2
  tau <- option.times[option.times >= t] - t

  d = outer(-0.0098*tau, log(1.5/s0), FUN = "+")/(0.0098 * sqrt(tau))

  p1 <- pnorm(d)
  p2 <- outer(exp((1/2*0.02^2 + 0.0098)*tau), s0 / 1.5, FUN = "*") * pnorm(d - 0.02*sqrt(tau)) 
  colSums((p1 - p2)*exp(-0.02*tau))*100
}

r3 <- matrix(0, n ,m)
timex <- time(x)
system.time(for (i in seq_along(timex)) {
  r3[i, ] <- g(x[i, ], timex[i])
})
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>       4.955       0.136       4.919
all(r3 == r2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

There might be ways to fully vectorize the function ...

Comment: Nice solution,
as it turns out mapply is slightly slower than my work around solution using apply twice, if the function f is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Cettt Interesting. Can you share an example for such a function?

Comment: @Cett I have updated the answer with benchmarks on my system.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the effort, in my case m = 10000, you are missing a zero :). But it's very interesting that for smaller column number mapply is indeed faster!

Comment: @Cettt I have updated the benchmark and found a partial vectorization which is much faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167750/discussion-between-cettt-and-ralf-stubner).